# Shapiro Wilk test is not working in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am working on a piece of R  markdown code. I am simply applying a Shapiro-Wilk test on a data. When I try to run the code in R studio in usual way, I don't get any issue. But when I try to run the code in r markdown, I am getting error provided below:

> Error in shapiro.test(Metric) : sample size must be between 3 and 5000
> Calls: ,Anonymius> ... summarise -> summarise.tbl_df -> summarise_impl
> _> shapiro.test In addition: There were 32 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Warnings are:

Code is:

```
normality_test_on_data_PPM <- final_combined_data %>% 
                              group_by(PPM) %>% 
                              summarise(W = shapiro.test(Metric)$statistic, P.value = shapiro.test(Metric)$p.value) %>% 
                              ungroup() %>% 
                              mutate(P_Value = format(round(P.value,3), nsmall = 3)) %>% 
                              select(PPM , P_Value) %>%
                              mutate(Normal_test = ifelse(P_Value >= 0.05, "Normal", "Not Normal"))
```

> #### Result of Normality Check

```
DT::datatable(normality_test_on_data_PPM)
```

Comment: Since the code isn't reproducible (we don't know what final_combined_data is/looks like), it's hard to pinpoint exactly what has gone wrong. However, `shapiro.test` is clearly unhappy about the sample size that is being passed in. Have you checked the sample size for each level of PPM?

Comment: Detail: The statisticians concerned were Samuel S. Shapiro and Martin B. Wilk, The use of Wilks may sometimes arise because people are thinking of the quite different Samuel S. Wilks, whose name is attached elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The Shapiro Wilk test admits only sample sizes <= 5000--for good reason, as in very large samples, even minute deviations from normality will qualify as significant at conventional levels. See the discussion here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/446262/can-a-sample-larger-than-5-000-data-points-be-tested-for-normality-using-shapiro. Alternatively, use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test `ks.test`, which has no such restriction or, perhaps even better, draw quantile-quantile plots, aka Q-Q plots, by using `qqnorm` and `qqline`: if the Q-Q plot deviates from the straight quantile line that's a good diagnostic indicating that the data violate normality.

**EDIT**:
Consider this illustration:

```
v1 <- rnorm(500)
v2 <- exp(rnorm(500))

par(mfrow = c(1,2), xpd = F)
qqnorm(v1, main = "Q-Q plot", cex.main = 0.85)
qqline(v1, col = "blue")
qqnorm(v2, main = "Q-Q plot", cex.main = 0.85)
qqline(v2, col = "blue")
```

The resulting plots clearly show which variable is normally, which is not normally distributed:
[image]

Comment: @Rama Kulkarni Check out very large samples, such as for example, `v1 <- rnorm(10000)` and `v2 <- exp(rnorm(10000))`; there the Q-Q plots work even better!